# What happens with the pendulum when we choose this angular velocity for a rotating platform?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

The problem is presented below:

[image]

I've managed to find the angular frequency of the pendulum using torque, and small-angle approximation. Finally, I wanted to check my expression and see whether it's resonable.

**Solution attempt**:

If we let $\hat{y}$ be the direction along the axle, and $\hat{x}$ be the direction along the swinging of the pendulum. Meaning, we form a coordinate system that rotates with the angular frequency $\Omega$. Since corioliseffects acts in $\hat{y}$, and our pendulum only swings in our chosen $\hat{x}$ - direction, it can be neglected.

However, we get a centrifugal force acting on our mass $m$ with size $m\Omega^2 l \sin(\theta)$ given that $\theta$ is the angle measured from the displacement of the string from the vertical.

Meaning, we can calculate the net torque around the fixed point on the axle:

$$M = -mgl\sin(\theta) + l \cos(\theta) m\Omega^2 l \sin(\theta) = I\theta''$$

Using small angle approximation, and $I = ml^2$, we get:

$$ l^2 \theta '' + (gl - \Omega^2 l^2) \theta = 0$$

Therefore,

$$ \omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}-\Omega^2}$$

Obviously, choosing $\Omega = 0$ gives us the trivial case $\omega = \sqrt{g/l}$, exactly the same angular frequency for a pendulum in a non-accelerating inertial system.

Furthermore, we see that if we pick $\Omega = \sqrt{g/l}$, we get that $\omega = 0$. Obviously for this case, we have that the net torque around the pivot is $0$. But what really happens for this pick of $\Omega$, intuitevly? Why is it exactly the angular frequency of a pendulum in a non-acclerating inertial-system? Does the pendulum just stay still in the center throughout the whole rotation?

Comment: You *should* include how you arrived at your first identity, in order for your question to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: And if $\Omega > \sqrt{g/l}$, then what?

Comment: @Gert Since I solved a 2nd order ODE. Looking back at it, the case you mentioned would result in that we wouldn't get an oscillation at all, and the solution would be something of the form of $Ae^{\omega t} + Be^{-\omega t}$. I guess that means that $\theta '' = 0$ in the case I asked about above, meaning $\theta' = k$ and $\theta = kt$ for some constant k ($\theta$ is the angular "displacement" of the pendulum).  Meaning the angular displacement would increase / decrease linearly? Am I right?

Comment: Which 2nd order ODE are you talking about?

Comment: I solved the angular frequency by solving this 2nd order ODE using torque equations: $ml^2 \theta '' + (gl-\Omega^2 l^2) \theta = 0$

Comment: In that ODE you cannot get rid of $m$, so the $\omega$ you present is incorrect. But w/o knowing how you derived the ODE it's hard to judge your approach. Have you watched this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXXt2ZjbPJY&ab_channel=PaulNord

Comment: @Gert Sorry, there should be no $m$ there, it was a mistype form me. And yes, I have watched that video.

Comment: @Gert I added my solution now. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for that. Your pendulum is in essence a Foucault pendulum but suspended at one of the poles. From what I understand the pendulum's natural frequency is not affected but the rotation induces precession. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum#Explanation_of_mechanics That's also what the video implies.

Comment: A Foucault pendulum can change its direction of swing relative to the platform.  This one cannot.

Comment: Once the mass moves moves away from the vertical position, it will seek a new equilibrium moving in a circle at a fixed radius. Horizontal and vertical force equations puts this equilibrium angle at : cos(θ) = g/($LΩ^2$).  Then the problem becomes finding the restoring torque for small displacements away from the equilibrium angle. You will assume small values for Δθ, not θ.

Comment: @R.W.Bird So, essentially, it will continue at a circular path viewed from a fixed set of axis, whilst within our coordinate system (rotating), it will be at a fixed distance away from the axis of rotation and it'll look like it won't move? Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: If moved away from the equilibrium position and released, it will oscillate about that position.

Comment: The problem statement is somewhat ambiguous, since one might also find an angular frequency of revolution for the pendulum bob as it moves in a circle.