# How can one calculate the torque around this point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

I'll link to one of my previous problems, since the setup is very much alike this one for the problem I'll be solving:

> [What happens with the pendulum when we choose this angular velocity for a rotating platform?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705156/284345)

So, my problem is that I want to calculate the torque about the point where the rod is attached to the axle.

We implement the same body fixed coordinate system as in the link above. $x$ in direction of swinging, $y$ in direction of axle, and $z$ in direction of rod such that we get a positively oriented basis. We know that the vector that affects the rotation of this body fixed coordiante system is given by:

$$ \vec{\omega} = [\Omega \sin(\theta), \dot{\theta}, \Omega \cos(\theta)]$$

Therefore, the torque exerted measured about the point $P$ on the axle for which the rod is attached to is:

$$ \vec{M_P} = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{L_P} = \dot{\vec{L_P}} + \vec{\omega} \times  \vec{L_P}$$

The moment of inertia around point $P$ is given by $I_xx = I_yy = ml^2$, the rest are just $0$. Therefore:

$$ \vec{L_P} = [\Omega \sin(\theta), \dot{\theta}, 0]$$

and thus:

$$ \vec{M_P} = ml^2 [\Omega \cos(\theta) \dot{\theta}, \ddot{\theta}, 0] + ml^2 [\Omega \sin(\theta), \dot{\theta}, \Omega \cos(\theta)] \times  [\Omega \sin(\theta), \dot{\theta}, 0] = ml^2 [0, \ddot{\theta} + \Omega^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta),0] $$

I've tried to solve this problem for a very long time now, but I don't really know what goes wrong in my solution. I've already managed to complete problems similar to these, but this one keeps bugging me out. Maybe there's some obvious error in my solution.

Comment: Here you refer to a "string". In the original question, it seems that the pendulum weight is attached to a rigid rod. Could you please clarify this.

Comment: A bit of nomenclature clarification. Torque _is not_ applied to any location as it is shared by an entire body, but torque _is_ measured at a point. the value of which changes depending on the distance of the net force applied.

Comment: @tom10 Yes, it's a rod sorry.

Comment: @JAlex Thanks for the clarification!!!

Comment: Check the equation for $\vec{L_P}$ as it is missing the mass terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer**

What you did wrong, is you forgot to the contribution of momentum to angular momentum.

$$ \vec{L}_P = \vec{L}_{\rm COM} + \vec{r}_{\rm COM} \times \vec{p} $$

The second thing wrong is the contribution of net force (including gravity) to the torque.

$$ \vec{M}_P = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L}_P = \dot{\vec{L}_P} + \vec{\omega} \times  \vec{L}_P + \vec{r}_{\rm COM} \times \vec{F} $$

The third issue is that gravity is missing. Finally, doing the equations of motion on a rotating frame requires additional fictitious forces and is generally to be avoided.

**The long answer follows**

In my nomenclature point *P* is fixed to the origin, and point *C* is the bob location $\vec{r}_C$

$$ \vec{r}_C = \pmatrix{ \ell \sin \theta \\ -\ell \cos \theta \\ 0} \tag{1}$$

using the following basis vectors that are at this instant aligned with the rotating axle in the following manner

[image: fig1]

The rotational velocity and acceleration in the world orientation is

$$ \vec{\omega} = \Omega \hat{y} + \dot{\theta} \hat{z} = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ \Omega \\ \dot{\theta} } \tag{2}$$

$$ \vec{\alpha} = \dot{\vec{\omega}} + \Omega \hat{y} \times \vec{\omega} = \pmatrix{\Omega \dot \theta \\ 0 \\ \ddot{\theta}} \tag{3}$$

Typically the equations of motion are summed (measured) at the center of mass, but you don't have to. It is simpler here to consider the origin (point *P*) as the summation point, and to express the equations of motion about this point since its motion is known. The velocity and accelerations are zero here $\vec{v}_P=0$, $\vec{a}_P = 0$.

$$ \begin{array}{r|c}
\text{Quantity} & \text{Definition}\\
\hline \text{body momentum} & \vec{p}=m\left(\vec{v}_{P}+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{C}\right)\\
\text{ang. momentum about }P & \vec{L}_{P}={\rm I}_{C}\vec{\omega}+\vec{r}_{C}\times\vec{p}\\
\text{net force} & \vec{F}+m\vec{g}=\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{p}\\
\text{torque about }P & \vec{\tau}_{P}=\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{L}_{P}+\vec{v}_{P}\times\vec{p}
\end{array} \tag{4}$$

Since the bob is a point mass, then the mass moment of inertia about it's center of mass is zero ${\rm I}_C=0$. The above four equations reduce to the following for this special case

$$\begin{gathered}\vec{p}=m\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{C}\right)\\
\vec{L}_{P}=\vec{r}_{C}\times\vec{p}\\
\vec{F}=m\left(\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_{C}\right)+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{p} - m\vec{g}\\
\vec{\tau}_{P}=\vec{r}_{C}\times\vec{F}
\end{gathered} \tag{5}$$

Use the values of $\vec{r}_C$, $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{\alpha}$ from above to get

$$ \small \begin{gathered}\vec{p}=m\begin{pmatrix}0\\
\Omega\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\ell\sin\theta\\
-\ell\cos\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m\dot{\theta}\ell\cos\theta\\
m\dot{\theta}\ell\sin\theta\\
-m\Omega\ell\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vec{L}_{P}=\begin{pmatrix}\ell\sin\theta\\
-\ell\cos\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}m\dot{\theta}\ell\cos\theta\\
m\dot{\theta}\ell\sin\theta\\
-m\Omega\ell\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\Omega m\ell^{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
\Omega m\ell^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\\
m\ell^{2}\dot{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vec{F}=m\begin{pmatrix}\Omega\dot{\theta}\\
0\\
\ddot{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\ell\sin\theta\\
-\ell\cos\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\
\Omega\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}m\dot{\theta}\ell\cos\theta\\
m\dot{\theta}\ell\sin\theta\\
-m\Omega\ell\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}-m\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-g\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{\theta}m\ell\cos\theta-m\ell\left(\dot{\theta}^{2}+\Omega^{2}\right)\sin\theta\\
\ddot{\theta}m\ell\sin\theta+m\ell\dot{\theta}^{2}\cos\theta+mg\\
-2\Omega\dot{\theta}m\ell\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vec{\tau}_{P}=\begin{pmatrix}\ell\sin\theta\\
-\ell\cos\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{\theta}m\ell\cos\theta-m\ell\left(\dot{\theta}^{2}+\Omega^{2}\right)\sin\theta\\
\ddot{\theta}m\ell\sin\theta+m\ell\dot{\theta}^{2}\cos\theta+mg\\
-2\Omega\dot{\theta}m\ell\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\Omega\dot{\theta}m\ell^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\\
2\Omega\dot{\theta}m\ell^{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
\ddot{\theta}m\ell^{2}+mg\ell-\Omega^{2}m\ell^{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gathered} \tag{6}$$

Given the free axle constraint $\hat{z} \cdot \vec{\tau}_P = 0$ the solution is $$ \ddot{\theta} = \Omega^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta - \tfrac{g}{\ell} \sin \theta $$

This makes physical sense since the more away from vertical it is, the more it tends to swing out, except once it is passes the balance angle gravity is going to reduce the angle. The balance point is

$$ \theta_{\rm balance} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{g}{\Omega^2 \ell} \right) \tag{7}$$

So in the absence of gravity this swings out to 90°, and without rotation the angle is zero.

---

#### Appendix I

The general equations of motion summed about a point *P* not the center of mass *C* are:

$$ \begin{gathered}\vec{p}=m\left(\vec{v}_{P}+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{C}\right)\\
\vec{L}_{P}={\rm I}_{C}\vec{\omega}+\vec{r}_{C}\times\vec{p}\\
\vec{F}=m\left(\vec{a}_{P}+\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_{C}+\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{C}\right)\right)\\
\vec{\tau}_{P}={\rm I}_{C}\vec{\alpha}+\vec{\omega}\times{\rm I}_{C}\vec{\omega}+\vec{r}_{C}\times\vec{F}+\vec{v}_{P}\times\vec{p}
\end{gathered} $$

where $\mathrm{I}_C$ is the mass moment of inertia tensor summed at the center of mass. All the vectors above must be described on the same inertial (non-rotating) basis vectors.

These relate the motion of *P*: $(\vec{a}_P,\; \vec{\alpha})$ and the loading at *P*: $(\vec{F},\; \vec{\tau}_P)$

Comment: Thank you really. Everything was super clear! I'll try to look at ur appendix and look for the derivations of these formulas so I'll be even more convinced of the result.

Comment: @Tanamas for the last formula you are going to need the fact that $\vec{v}_C \times \vec{p} = \vec{v}_C \times m \vec{v}_C = 0$

Comment: @Tanamas let me know here if you need help. The last one can be derived from the transformation of torque $\tau_P = \tau_C + r_C \times F$, transformation of momentum $L_P = L_C + r_C \times p$ and the definition $\tau_C = d\,L_C / dt$